# Forcing Script Order from registerScript Method in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I created a widget that registers its own script like below

```
class MyWidget extends CWidget {
    public function run(){
        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(__CLASS__, <<<JAVASCRIPT
var a = "Hello World!";
JAVASCRIPT
        , CClientScript::POS_END);
    }
}
```

And in the layout, I call the widget like this

```
<?php $this->widget('MyWidget');?>
<?php echo $content;?>
```

But in a view file, I need the variable declared by that widget.

```
<?php 
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('script', <<<JAVASCRIPT
    alert(a);
JAVASCRIPT
    , CClientScript::POS_END);
?>
```

Note that in both registerScript method I use POS_END as the script position since I intend to put all of the scripts (including the CoreScript e.g. jQuery, jQueryUI etc) after the `<body>` tag.

The problem is that the rendered script will show the one from the view file and after that the one from the widget.

```
alert(a);
var a = "Hello World!";
```

As we can see, the above code won't work so I need to put the the second line above the first line.

Any idea on how to force the order? I'm okay with extending the `CClientScript` (and creating a new `registerScript` method) as long as all of the scripts will be rendered in the end position and I don't have to pull those inline Javascript codes above to a new package or file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I finally find a hack to do this. I extend a new `ClientScript` class and modify the `registerScript` method so it will accept another param `$level`.

```
public function registerScript($id, $script, $position = self::POS_END, $level = 1);
```

Think about `$level` just like `z-index` in CSS, except the greater the number of `$level` is, the lower the position of the script will be.

For example

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('script1', '/** SCRIPT #1 **/', CClientScript::POS_END, 1);
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('script2', '/** SCRIPT #2 **/', CClientScript::POS_END, 2);
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('script3', '/** SCRIPT #3 **/', CClientScript::POS_END, 1);
```

Even though `script3` is declared after `script2`, in the rendered script, it will show above `script2` since the `$level` value of `script2` is greater than `script3`'s.

Here's my solution's code. It's working like what I want although I'm not sure if the arranging method is optimized enough.

```
/**
 * ClientScript manages Javascript and CSS.
 */
class ClientScript extends CClientScript {
    public $scriptLevels = array();

    /**
     * Registers a piece of javascript code.
     * @param string $id ID that uniquely identifies this piece of JavaScript code
     * @param string $script the javascript code
     * @param integer $position the position of the JavaScript code.
     * @param integer $level the rendering priority of the JavaScript code in a position.
     * @return CClientScript the CClientScript object itself (to support method chaining, available since version 1.1.5).
     */
    public function registerScript($id, $script, $position = self::POS_END, $level = 1) {
        $this->scriptLevels[$id] = $level;
        return parent::registerScript($id, $script, $position);
    }

    /**
     * Renders the registered scripts.
     * Overriding from CClientScript.
     * @param string $output the existing output that needs to be inserted with script tags
     */
    public function render(&$output) {
        if (!$this->hasScripts)
            return;

        $this->renderCoreScripts();

        if (!empty($this->scriptMap))
            $this->remapScripts();

        $this->unifyScripts();

        //===================================
        //Arranging the priority
        $this->rearrangeLevels();
        //===================================

        $this->renderHead($output);
        if ($this->enableJavaScript) {
            $this->renderBodyBegin($output);
            $this->renderBodyEnd($output);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Rearrange the script levels.
     */
    public function rearrangeLevels() {
        $scriptLevels = $this->scriptLevels;
        foreach ($this->scripts as $position => &$scripts) {
            $newscripts = array();
            $tempscript = array();
            foreach ($scripts as $id => $script) {
                $level = isset($scriptLevels[$id]) ? $scriptLevels[$id] : 1;
                $tempscript[$level][$id] = $script;
            }
            foreach ($tempscript as $s) {
                foreach ($s as $id => $script) {
                    $newscripts[$id] = $script;
                }
            }
            $scripts = $newscripts;
        }
    }
}
```

So I just need to put the class as the clientScript component in the config

```
'components' => array(
  'clientScript' => array(
      'class' => 'ClientScript'
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try register to HEAD

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(__CLASS__, <<<JAVASCRIPT
var a = "Hello World!";
JAVASCRIPT
, CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
```

Comment: My intention is rendering all of the scripts on the end. The thing is the script in the widget depends on jQuery, and I put all of the coreScripts in the end by setting the `coreScriptPosition` field (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#coreScriptPosition-detail) as POS_END.

Comment: Well, U have bad idea, or U have to split var declaration to HEAD, body of widgets script ot END, or U have to change END to READY: Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('script', <<<JAVASCRIPT
    alert(a);
JAVASCRIPT
    , CClientScript::POS_READY);

Answer (score 1):

I've contributed a patch to Yii to allow ordering (prepend, append, number)

you can find it here
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/pull/2263

if it did not get its place into you, then you can extend CClientScript to your own class to apply my changes

but in general properly written JS should work independent of order
for example instead of defining some global scope vars you can assign them as properties to window (accessing a non-existing property does not throw an error in js)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to extend CClienScript. A simple solution to this problem would be to create a $script array in your controller in your controller and add the view scripts to that variable. In your layout file You would register the scripts stored in your $scripts array after you have registered the ones you want to be rendered before it. e.g.:

**in your controller**

```
public $scripts = [];
```

**In your layout:**

```
$baseURL = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;
$clientScript = Yii::app()->clientScript;
$clientScript->registerScriptFile( $baseURL . '/js/jquery.min.js', CClientScript::POS_END );
$clientScript->registerScriptFile( $baseURL . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', CClientScript::POS_END);
```

**and in your view**

```
<?php array_push($this->scripts,"/js/summernote.min.js");?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the CClientScript class as @Petra said, here is the code I am using, after using @Petra code and didn't worked out for me.

```
class ClientScript extends CClientScript {

public $scriptLevels;

public function registerScript($id, $script, $position = null, $level = 1, array $htmlOptions = array()) {
    $this->scriptLevels[$id] = $level;
    return parent::registerScript($id, $script, $position, $htmlOptions);
}

public function render(&$output) {
    foreach ($this->scripts as $key => $value) {
        $this->scripts[$key] = $this->reorderScripts($value);
    }
    parent::render($output);
}

public function reorderScripts($element) {
    $tempScripts = array();
    $buffer = array();
    foreach ($element as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($this->scriptLevels[$key])) {
            $tempScripts[$this->scriptLevels[$key]][$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    ksort($tempScripts);
    foreach ($tempScripts as $value) {
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            $buffer[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $buffer;
}

}
```

and then, go to your config file, and in the components section edit the following:

```
'components' => array(
    .
    .
    'clientScript' => array(
        'class' => 'ClientScript'
    ),
)
```