# Set id to script by registerScript in yii

Tags: php, yii

I find very more posts about the problem, but all answers was unhelpful. For example [Forcing Script Order from registerScript Method in Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651861/forcing-script-order-from-registerscript-method-in-yii) and [yii CClientScript docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScript-detail). Above posts had writen

```
registerScript(string $id, string $script, integer $position=NULL, array $htmlOptions=array ( ))
```

For getting above script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="some_id">
    console.log("sasasasas");
    //js code
</script>
```

I have piece of code:

```
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$cs->registerScript(__CLASS__ . '#' . $this->id . 'Ex', '
        console.log("sasasasas");'
        //js code
   , CClientScript::POS_READY,  array('id="some_id"' ) 
);
```

But I could not get script like I expected. I got script without `id="some_id"`.Could anybody can help me for find what I missed ?

**EDIT**
Does not work both versions:

```
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$cs->registerScript(__CLASS__ . '#' . $this->id . 'Ex', '
        console.log("sasasasas");'
        //js code
   , CClientScript::POS_READY,  array('id'=> 'some_id' ) 
);
```

and

```
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$cs->registerScript('some_id', '
        console.log("sasasasas");'
        //js code
   , ) 
);
```

Comment: try changing array('id="some_id"' ) to array('id'=>'some_id')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have to change the line

```
array('id="some_id"')
```

to

```
array('id' => 'some_id')
```

Answer (score 1):

May be someone will come across later with the problem. And I advice them, mustn't do my mistake. [@Chris answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25765416/1746258) is right, `registerScript()` sets an id when you render view with `render()`, but when you use `renderPartial()` `registerScript()` does not set an id to script. You can find a solution from [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188391/yii-renderpartial-proccessoutput-true-avoid-duplicate-js-request)